# Bad to set socket to null instead of using ".close()" in Java

Tags: java, sockets, null, connection

The question says it all; is it better to use the ".close()" method instead of just setting the socket to null? But can't the ".close()" method throw an exception, at that time can I just set it to null?

And once I close a socket, just safe measures set the socket to null after I call ".close()", can I reuse that same socket again with a different connection? Or do I need to recreate a whole new socket.

Answer (score 3):

The question is meaningless. Setting a *variable* to null does nothing to the *socket,* except possibly make it eligible for GC. If you want to close a socket, close it, or better still close the outermost output stream or writer you have wrapped around its output stream. The fact that this can throw an exception mustn't deter you.

Answer (score 1):

> But cant the ".close()" method throw an exception

It may, so wrap close() also in try/catch. If close() fails, that's ok you tried failed, make it `null` and continue.

> And once I close a socket, just safe measures set the socket to null
>   after I call ".close()", can I reuse that same socket again with a
>   different connection? Or do I need to recreate a whole new socket.

Closing socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream. Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket needs to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is better to close the socket before setting it to null.  I'd say it's safe to set it to null after you call close, whether or not it throws an exception.  If you set it to null before closing it, the socket will still exist and occupy the port until it is destroyed at some unknown time later by the jvm.

Yes you will have to make a new socket after closing it.

Comment: It's not 'better'. It's *essential*, regardless of setting the variable to null, which is *pointless*.

Comment: It is better, and essential.  Setting the variable to null isn't pointless, in some cases it will help the gc free the memory sooner.  Also it's a quick way to determine if the socket exists or not.

Comment: 'Better and essential' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Yeah that's true.  Thanks for letting me know.  If you'd like to argue _pointless_ things more we can do that elsewhere.

Comment: You can't set the variable to null before closing the socket, unless you save a copy in another variable, which you set to null after closing it, which is merely ridiculous.